# Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found in 'Ionic app'

Tags: node.js, angularjs, ionic-framework

I cloned an IONIC application from project from Github, installed  npm and bower on my Windows 10 environment, now when i run 
    `ionic cordova run android`
I get an error saying
    `Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.`
Even though i have angular installed, at first i was getting a different error:
    The run command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.
But then i tried uninstalling/updating/reinstalling many Angular versions, now i'm getting the error saying Angular.json is not found.
How can i fix this?

Comment: you are missing the angular.json file which is normally in the root folder.. check this [project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-th5xtd) you will see an example angular.json file there

Comment: @EnesYalçın The thing is the project does not contain any angular.json file as it is in its repository, should i create this file manually?

Comment: Please try to add it to the project! Do you happen to know if you updated angular?

Comment: I updated Angular several times and tested many versions, how do i add that file to the project?

Comment: if you can send the github repo I can try to reproduce it.. Meanwhile try to add the angular.json file from [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-th5xtd) to your project.. it could be that you have to adapt some parts of the angular.json file